# Customize WebOptimizer Cache Busting Algorithm

Tags: c#, azure-waf, weboptimizer

I am using [ASP.NET Core Web Optimizer](https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer). It has cache busting feature that will append a unique string to the end of script or CSS links.

A sample of the appended string is like this: `....script.js?v=8UnFL4zesLGMnNgeUbnu9OOWly7_ES--Qx-E_tWr2NQ`

This works well, unfortunately, our corporate firewall does not like this and block this URL as **SQL injection**... (ok you may laugh out loud..., go ahead). The firewall is Azure WAF.

I know better than fighting the bureaucracy in my company, so is there any way I could customize the algorithm to sidestep this issue?

I imagine, for our intent and purpose, using `DateTime.Ticks` would be enough, that would also appease the firewall.

Comment: I believe you cannot extend it, because this is how it's defined: https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer/blob/master/src/WebOptimizer.Core/FileVersionProvider.cs#L94. And this class is used directly in `BaseTagHelper` without DI or something like that. So best option is to ask developers to add such possibility, or do that yourself and compile your own version of this library

Comment: Yea I inspected the code and tried to subclass `Asset` class, unfortunately, it is `internal`.